# JQuery Progress Circle + fade page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using JQuery how would I make the page dim / fade and display a progress circle in the center which is animated? I'd like to do this when the user fills out a form and clicks submit and is awaiting a response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use the block ui plugin - http://jquery.malsup.com/block/

Then call this before doing the ajax request

```
$('body').block({ message: '<img src="loading.gif" />' });
```

And then this is the success method

```
$('body').unblock();
```